# SuperSU binaries won't install to my HTC One M8

Tags: rooting, root-access, verizon, superuser, htc-one-m8

I am following [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2708628) guide to root my HTC One M8. I just need root, I don't need a custom ROM.

I have gotten to step 7 (weaksauce). I can install weaksauce fine and it roots my device (at least, it says it roots it).

However, when I try to run SuperSU (downloaded from the Android market, latest version) it says `The SU binary needs to be updated. Continue?` It says this in my notification bar as well. I click `Continue` and it says `Installing, please wait. If you see this message for more than five minutes please restart and try again`. After about 30 seconds, it says `Installation failed ! Please reboot and try again`.

I've tried it multiple times with all forms of rebooting (adb reboot, holding power button, etc) as well as a factory reset (which put me back down to 4.2.2), however it keeps giving me this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this issue and there are 3 ways to try to get around this.

You will need a custom recovery to attempt 1. or you can use Odin alternatively for 2. below. The `superSU` binaries are often (but not always) installed via [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery) and the app itself gives this option.

1. When `superSU` asks you to update the binaries, rather than select 'Normal' select 'Recovery' and see if it can install that way.
2. Flash `superSU.zip` directly in your recovery or `Odin`. [Here is the link to Chainfire's latest version](http://download.chainfire.eu/452/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.02.zip). I have tried this myself and it fixed the issue for me on a number of devices.
3. Install an alternative super user app from the market. (This can be messy, and you need to ensure `superSU` is completely removed)

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve perm root by unlocking Bootloader then flashing a custom recovery. This cannot be done in Odin as the previous answer dictates. It must be done via adb. There are a couple of methods that work for unlocking the Bootloader but the only gurantee is Sunshine. After the Bootloader is unlocked flash a custom recovery(TWRP,CM OR PhilZ touch) via adb. The latter is what I would recommend if your used to using CM on previous devices. There are plenty of tutorials as well as how to vids on YouTube and it is really quite simple. Hope this helps